# EF Core - add conditional where based on field value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I would like to add additional where clauses to my query based on the value of a of a field (dateType)

- if dateType = 1 then (StartDate <= Now && EndDate => Now) //specific date range
- if dateType = 2 then (Period => Now.Month  && Year =>Now.Year) //month
- if dateType = 3 then (Period => Now.Month /4) //quarter

I tried the ternary operator but that doesnt work, here is the start of my query.

```
        var query = from e in context.Events
            join c in context.EventCategories on e.CategoryId equals c.CategoryId
            join o in context.Owners on e.OwnerId equals o.OwnerId
            where !e.IsDeleted 
                  && (e.DateType == 1 ? (e.StartDateTimeUtc <= DateTime.UtcNow && e.EndDateTimeUtc =>DateTime.UtcNow))
```

using EF Core 2.2

Comment: @GertArnold :) fair enough, it doesnt work :), i just posted what I have so far so that it doesnt seem like I want everyone to write the  query for me, just need guidance on how to implement the select case

Comment: In the same pseudocode: use `(dateType = 1 && (StartDate <= Now && EndDate > Now)) || (dateType = 2 && (Period => Now.Month && Year =>Now.Year) ...`

Comment: woaaa thanks budd, thats what I was looking for, i feel like a dummy now :)

Answer (score 1):

Final answer thanks to Gert Arnold providing direction in comments to OP

```
    var query = from e in context.Events
                    join c in context.EventCategories on e.CategoryId equals c.CategoryId
                    join o in context.Owners on e.OwnerId equals o.OwnerId
                    where !e.IsDeleted && (e.DateType == 1 && e.StartDateTimeUtc <= DateTime.UtcNow && e.EndDateTimeUtc >= DateTime.UtcNow) //specific date
                                           || (e.DateType == 2 && e.Period >= DateTime.UtcNow.Month && e.Year >= DateTime.UtcNow.Year) // month
                                           || (e.DateType == 3 && e.Period >= DateTime.UtcNow.Month / 3 && e.Year >= DateTime.UtcNow.Year) //quarter
```